# send data to specific socket

Tags: node.js

How can in send data to a specific connected socket in Node.js? I want to write a server that accepts incoming sockets, assigns them an id, and then when messages are sent from the other client, it is directed to that one. I guess you could say similar to a private message.

Also, is there a way to emit data EXCLUDING one socket?

Comment: like maybe a private message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are similar questions on stackoverflow, here's an example:

[Sending a message to a client via its socket.id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467784/sending-a-message-to-a-client-via-its-socket-id)

Quick version:

```
io.sockets.socket(id).emit('hello');
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess i just didn't know how to word it. The is my first day   using node js and i can't hardly find anyithing  to help  beginners learn.