# Emit to Socket IO socket.id

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am trying to emit to a particular socket ID:

```
socket(user[playID]).emit('correct', data);
```

But I'm getting:

```
TypeError: object is not a function
```

if I log out `user[playID]` I do get a valid socket ID.

Appreciated!

Here is my setup in case I'm missing something:.

```
// Tell Socket.io to pay attention
servio  = io.listen(server);

// Tell HTTP Server to begin listening for connections on port 3250
sock    = server.listen(3250);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should do it

```
servio.sockets.socket(id).emit('hello');
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8468296/1146431) covers the same/similar topic. In short, consider keeping a reference to the connected clients yourself and emit to them as desired, rather than relying on socket.io's internals, which could change.

Answer (score 3):

Per http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/,

> Each Socket in Socket.IO is identified by a random, unguessable,
>   unique identifier Socket#id. For your convenience, each socket
>   automatically joins a room identified by this id.

You emit to a room like:

```
io.to('some room').emit('some event')
```

If you want to emit to just a specific socket.id, just replace 'some room' with the associated id.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this is:

```
var players = [];

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){

    socket.on('skt_init', function (data) {
            var player = new Object();
            player.id = data.id;
            player.socket = socket.id;
            players.push(player);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {        
        var len = 0;

        for(var i=0, len=players.length; i<len; ++i ) {
            var p = players[i];

            if(p.socket == socket.id){
                players.splice(i,1);
                break;
            }
        }
    });

    socket.on('skt_event', function(data, id_player){
        var len = 0;

        for(var i=0, len=players.length; i<len; ++i ) {
            var p = players[i];
            if(p.id == id_player){
                io.sockets.socket(p.socket).emit('correct', data);
                break;
            }
        }
    });
```

Hope that helps somewhat.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: in socket.io-1.4 you have to prepend "/#" to socket id ( very frustrating that it doesnt work now). you can also view all connected sockets from backend as io.sockets.connected

```
io.to( "/#" + socket_id).emit("event_name",{data:true})
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
servio.sockets.sockets[playId].emit(...)
```

Comment: No I still have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since socket.io doesn't provide a stable API to get the socket from a socket's ID, you can simply (and easily) keep track of them with an object keyed by socket IDs.

```
sockets_by_id = {}

io.on "connection", (socket)->
    sockets_by_id[socket.id] = socket

sockets_by_id[socket_id].emit event, data...
```

(^CoffeeScript^)