# emit a message to all sockets of one specific user in node.js

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am currently using `Node.js` and it's working very well, for each user I save sockets. also saving all browser tab sockets ID. I mean each tab has a unique socket. so a unique user have multiple sockets. Here is what I do.

```
usersObj = {};

io.sockets.on( 'connection', function( socket ) {
    socket.on("new user", function( data, callback ) {


        if ( data.id in usersObj ){ // if user is in usersObj, save it's new socket.id

            usersObj[data.id].sockets_ids.push( socket.id );

            // how to send a message to all sockets of a specific user
            // usersObj[data.id].sockets.socket.emit( "hi", { data: "Hi!" } ); this does not work.

        } else { // if user is not in usersObj, make a new object and save it's socket.

            usersObj[data.id] = {
                "sockets_ids" : [ socket.id ] // array for all sockets id of this user
            }

        }
    });
});
```

Now userObj for user with ID 10, and user with ID 11, is this:

```
usersObj = {
    10 = {
        sockets_ids = [
            asdf9877687sdfasdf,    // sample socket ID for browser tab 1
            459djhfskdhjfasd8f,    // sample socket ID for browser tab 2
            oewurwoer845935739     // sample socket ID for browser tab 3
        ]

    },
    11 = {
        sockets_ids = [
            xcdf987sdfsddfasdf,    // sample socket ID for browser tab 1
            ty9djhfskdhjf45344,    // sample socket ID for browser tab 2
            sawurwoer84593xcvx     // sample socket ID for browser tab 3
        ]

    },

}
```

Now I want to emit a message `Hi!` to all sockets belongs to user with ID 10.
So I should get sockets by their ID which is in user's sockets_ids array and emit to that socket my message.
How can I do that?
This is completely wrong and does not work.
`usersObj[data.id].sockets_ids.socket.emit( "hi", { data: "Hi!" } );`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop through the `sockets_ids` like so:

```
usersObj[data.id].sockets_ids.forEach(function(id){
    io.sockets.socket(id).emit("hi", { data: "Hi!" });
});
```

Also you should consider storing the actual socket object instead of the socket.id, as the method utilized above is an internal method of socket.io, and thus is not reliable. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467784/sending-a-message-to-a-client-via-its-socket-id/8468296#8468296).

Comment: thanks, I am saving actual sockets right now, I was thinking about a better code to reduce ram usage. so is there any way to see the size of variables in javascript? I want to know the size of each socket object...